# how do i overload << to output the string value for an enum

Tags: c++, enums

Implement class Day which represents a day of the week. Overload operator+=, operator-=, operator++ (prefix), and operator-- (prefix), and operator<< as described below.

**would I use a switch statement in the overloaded << definition to cout the string value of the enum? The code in the main is the test to see if our code runs properly ( still need to finish defining the operators)
should i reply on implicit conversion between enum and int? i didnt know how to put enum in the parameters (if thats even appropriate)**

**This is my code:**

```
/*
Class Implementation for Day of the week
includes overloaded operators 
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;



class Day
{
public:
    enum Dia { SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY };
    Day(int); // Default Constructor
    Day(const Day&); // Copy Contructor
    Day& operator+=(const Day&); // Overloaded +=
    int getDummy() const;
private:
    int dummyDay;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Day&);


int main()

{
    Day today = Day::WEDNESDAY;
    cout << today;
    std::cout << today << std::endl; // "Wednesday"

    Day generic_day; // default constructor-- default day is Sunday
    std::cout << generic_day << std::endl; // "Sunday"

    ++generic_day;
    std::cout << generic_day << std::endl; // "Monday"

    today += 5;
    std::cout << today << std::endl; // "Monday"

    today -= 1;
    std::cout << today << std::endl; // "Sunday
    return 0;
}
Day::Day(int DayDay = 0)
{
    dummyDay = DayDay;
};

Day& Day::operator+=(const Day& z)
{
    dummyDay += z.dummyDay;
    return *this;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Day& z)
{

    return out;
}

Day::Day(const Day& z)
{
    dummyDay = z.dummyDay;
}

int Day::getDummy() const
{
    return dummyDay;
}
```

Comment: Is there a deeper reason why you use `int` instead of `Day::Dia` in the constructor and `getDummy` signatures? It looks like a very weak abstraction to me. Also adding two days seems wrong to me. What is Monday plus Tuesday? `operator+=` IMHO should take `int` as argument, not `Day`. Also note that you definitely should add some modulo operation there, since as is you'll sometimes get invalid dummyDay values.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a `std::vector<std::string>` in which you store  the strings of all week days.
`std::vector<std::string> weekOfDay = {"Monday", etc...};`

Or even better as pointed by @celtschk a `std::array<std::string, 7>` which is a lighter choice.

Then you can get the current day of week with something `oss << weekOfDay[day.getDummy()]` where `oss` is your `std::ofstream`.

If you can't use `std::vector`, `std::array` or C++11 features, use a simple `std::string` array.

Comment: Since it is a constant array that is never changed, I don't see a value in using a vector. A built-in array (or `std::array` in C++11) IMHO is the best option here.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think of `std::array`, I guess it's a bad habit I have of using `std::vector` in this case. Answer edited @celtschk

Answer (score 2):

You can overload an `enum`. You don't need to create a whole new class you can simply create the overloads for the `enum` and call them whenever; see usage in `main` function. Use C++ 11 with the `enum class` and implement the following, I tested it and it is working:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum class Day
{
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
};

Day& operator++(Day& day)
{
    int i = static_cast<int>(day) + 1;

    // Handle wrap around.
    if(i > 6)   // Saturday = 6
        i = 0;  // Sunday = 0

    day = static_cast<Day>(i);

    return day;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Day day)
{
    switch(day)
    {
        case Day::Sunday:    return os << "Sunday";
        case Day::Monday:    return os << "Monday";
        case Day::Tuesday:   return os << "Tuesday";
        case Day::Wednesday: return os << "Wednesday";
        case Day::Thursday:  return os << "Thursday";
        case Day::Friday:    return os << "Friday";
        case Day::Saturday:  return os << "Saturday";
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Day day = Day::Monday;
    cout << day << endl;

    ++day;
    cout << day << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For an enum, `const Day&` makes no sense. Just pass by value. It's both more clean *and* cheaper.

Comment: I changed the code from `const Day& day` to `const Day day`. You're right, the reference doesn't make sense in this case.